# How to add an element after a slider thumbnail active scrowller?

Tags: css

I'm trying to add an image after the smart slider thumbnail active scrowller with CSS code as a pseudo element but isn't working

```
div#n2-ss-2 .nextend-thumbnail-default .nextend-thumbnail-scroller > div.n2-active {
 cursor: default;
 border: 3px solid #b3b3b3;
}


div#n2-ss-2 .nextend-thumbnail-default .nextend-thumbnail-scroller > div.n2-active::after {
 cursor: default;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -13px;
 left: calc(50% - 20px);
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 border-color: #b3b3b3 transparent transparent;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 16px 18px 0;
 content: url('https://.../wp-content/uploads/2018/09/drop-down-arrow_icon-icons.com_72774.svg');
 display: inline-block;
 z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected the element? CSS may be overridden.

Comment: There is no pseudo element on your CSS.

Comment: Sorry I've forgot to add the correct code that I was trying. 
It was 
    div#n2-ss-2 .nextend-thumbnail-default .nextend-thumbnail-scroller > div.n2-active::after {

Comment: @Ramesh I think that you're right, how do I fix it? I've try "position: relative and z-index" but didn't work as well

Comment: @ThagesW.Almeida You need to include your custom css file as the last one. If you still have the problem you can have `!important` to the css that you want to be appear which can not be overridden.